# Non-linear (e.g. RBF kernel) SVM with SCAD penalties implementation

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, svm, feature-selection

Is there one? I think there's a penalizedSVM package in R but it looks to use a linear kernel.  Can't quite tell from the documentation. If it's linear, is there a R package that lets me calculate the kernel matrix so I can transform my data? I was thinking I could combine the two together to run a RBF SVM with SCAD penalties.